# Is it possible in Java to return enum name and values together?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, enums, jackson

Is it possible to get ENUM name and labels together?
Like:

```
[
    {"COMBUSTIVEL", "Combustível"},
    {"TROCADEOLEO", "Troca de Óleo"},
    {"PNEUDIANTEIRO", "Pneu Dianteiro"},
    {"PNEUTRASEIRO", "Pneu Traseiro"},
    {"CORRENTE", "Corrente"},
    {"RELACAO", "Relação"}
]
```

I'm using Spring MVC, but I think it is irrelevant.

I tried to override the `toString()` method, but unfortunately it did not work.

My code:

```java
public enum Categoria {
    COMBUSTIVEL("Combustível"), 
    TROCADEOLEO("Troca de óleo"), 
    PNEUDIANTEIRO("Pneu dianteiro"), 
    PNEUTRASEIRO("Pneu traseiro"), 
    CORRENTE("Corrente"), 
    RELACAO("Relação");

    private String label;

    Categoria(String item){
        this.label = item;
    }

    public String getLabel(){
        return this.label;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public String[][] getList(){
        Categoria[] values = Categoria.values();

        return ?;
    }

}
```

The results is:

```
[
    "COMBUSTIVEL",
    "TROCADEOLEO",
    "PNEUDIANTEIRO",
    "PNEUTRASEIRO",
    "CORRENTE",
    "RELACAO"
]
```

Comment: A tried get a array, but not sucess:  public String[][] getList(){
  Categoria[] values = Categoria.values();
  
  return ?;
 }

Comment: Don't override `toString` on enums; it causes lots of confusion for everyone else. Use the `getLabel` instead (and you can usually make all fields on an enum `final`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```
        public static String[][] getList(){
            Categoria[] values = Categoria.values();

            String[][] result = new String[values.length][2]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
                String[] pair = {values[i].name(), values[i].toString()};
                result[i] = pair;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Why a 2D array? Your solution may work OK for storing, but not as good for retrieving values. A Map will be more effective. It would also allow to store the same enumeration multiple times without restriction unless you add strenuous code to prevent it.

Comment: The question asks for `2D` array: the return type of the `getList` is `String[][]`.It is better to ask OP. I guess the API here is consumed by some client that needs an array.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options how you can achieve that. You could simply return a map with name as key and label as value:

```
public static Map<String, String> getList() {
    return Arrays.stream(Categoria.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Categoria::name, Categoria::getLabel));
}
```

If you want a nested array you can use this:

```
public static String[][] getList() {
    return Arrays.stream(Categoria.values())
            .map(c -> new String[] {c.name(), c.getLabel()})
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

Another options would be to map your enum to a custom object or create a custom serializer.

Comment: Both methods need to be static, otherwise you can't call them in a useful manner.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your toString method to

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name() + ", " + getLabel();
}
```

And then change your getList()

```
public String[][] getList(){
    Categoria[] values = Categoria.values();
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Categoria value : values) {
      resultList.add(value.toString);
    }
    return resultList.toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this much simpler :

```
public enum Categoria {
    COMBUSTIVEL("Combustível"), TROCADEOLEO("Troca de óleo"), PNEUDIANTEIRO("Pneu dianteiro"),
    PNEUTRASEIRO("Pneu traseiro"), CORRENTE("Corrente"), RELACAO("Relação");

    private String label;

    Categoria(String item) {
        this.label = item;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public static String myText() {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        int i = 0;
        Categoria[] categoria = Categoria.values();
        str.append("[\n");
        for(Categoria c : categoria) {
            str.append("\t{\""+c.getLabel()+"\", \""+categoria[i].name()+"\"}");
            if((i + 1) < categoria.length) {
                str.append(",\n");
            }
            i++;
        }
        str.append("\n]");

        return str.toString();        
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Categoria.myText());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
[
    {"Combustível", "COMBUSTIVEL"},
    {"Troca de óleo", "TROCADEOLEO"},
    {"Pneu dianteiro", "PNEUDIANTEIRO"},
    {"Pneu traseiro", "PNEUTRASEIRO"},
    {"Corrente", "CORRENTE"},
    {"Relação", "RELACAO"}
]
```